# Function name in parentheses after function call in Python

Tags: python, functions, methods

I ran into these lines of code in the QPYTHON Android app. They are part of a sample that uses the Bottle module to create a simple Web server that seems to work fine.

```
app = Bottle()
app.route('/', method='GET')(home)
app.route('/__exit', method=['GET','HEAD'])(__exit)
app.route('/__ping', method=['GET','HEAD'])(__ping)
app.route('/assets/<filepath:path>', method='GET')(server_static)
```

Now, I know that all the functions in parentheses after the call have already been wrapped with the @route decorator above this. For example:

```
@route('/__ping')
def __ping():
    return "ok"
```

But I have no idea what putting things in parentheses after other things does in Python, and after trying a hundred different permutations of "functions in parentheses after functions" I gave up.

I throw myself on the mercy of the Exchange.

Comment: It looks like the function `route` returns another function, and that dynamically selected function is then called with the argument `home` (for instance). Look up *higher-order functions*.

Comment: *"putting things in parentheses after other things"* **calls** the other things - `foo(bar, baz)` calls `foo` with the arguments `bar` and `baz`, `foo(bar)(baz)` calls `foo` with the argument `bar` and then calls *whatever `foo` returns* with the argument `baz`. In this case, `@route` is a **decorator** (i.e. a callable that returns a callable) that takes parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929107/python-decorators-with-parameters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
app.route('/', method='GET')(home)
```

... Is the same as this:

```
func = app.route('/', method='GET')
func(home)
```

In other words, `app.route(...)` returns a function, which is then called.

Answer (score 3):

```
def a():
    def b(arg):
        return arg * 2
    return b

print(a()(5))

c = a()
print(c(5))
```

```
Output:
10
10
```

You are basically providing an argument for the function within the function, a.k.a inner function